# String Comparison, .NET and non breaking space

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding

I have an app written in C# that does a lot of string comparison. The strings are pulled in from a variety of sources (including user input) and are then compared. However I'm running into problems when comparing space '32' to non-breaking space '160'. To the user they look the same and so they expect a match. But when the app does the compare, there is no match.

What is the best way to go about this? Am I going to have to go to all parts of the code that do a string compare and manually normalize non-breaking spaces to spaces? Does .NET offer anything to help with that? (I've tried all the compare options but none seem to help.)

It has been suggested that I normalize the strings upon receipt and then let the string compare method simply compare the normalized strings. I'm not sure it would be straight-forward to do that because what is a normalized string in the first place. What do I normalize it too? Sure, for now I can convert non-breaking spaces to breaking spaces. But what else can show up? Can there potentially be very many of these rules? Might they even be conflicting. (In one case I want to use a rule and in another I don't.)

Comment: You can edit your own question to add more information or provide clarification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it were me, I would 'normalize' the strings as I 'pulled them in'; probably with a string.Replace().  Then you won't need to change your comparisons anywhere else.

**Edit**: Mark, that's a tough one.  Its really up to you, or you clients, as to what is a 'normalized' string.  I've been in a similar situation where the customer demanded that strings like:

```
I have 4 apples.
I have four apples.
```

were actually equal.  You may need separate normalizers for different situations.  Either way, I would still do the normalization upon retrieval of the original strings.

Comment: Yep, I would normalize the strings to what you care about with your own function that calls string.Replace and then does the compare.

Comment: guys how do i post a follow up question or a clarification question to this proposed answer? Do i do it here? This only allows 255 characters

Comment: @Mark: Edit your question to include follow-ups or clarifications.

Comment: Haha, thanks - the example comparison (4 == four) made me laugh, but also made me think about what the definition of "equal" should mean.  Maybe we need a string.Equivalent() method.

Answer (score 41):

I went through lots of pain to find this simple answer. The code below uses a regular expression to replace non breaking spaces with normal spaces.

```
string cellText = "String with non breaking spaces.";
cellText = Regex.Replace(cellText, @"\u00A0", " ");
```

Hope this helps, Dan

Comment: Doesn't the @ stop the escape character from working? Shouldn't it be cellText.Replace("\u00A0", " ")?

Comment: @jpmcclung yes. See "Char Objects and Unicode Characters" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx. FWIW, `cellText.Replace('\u00A0', ' ')` is even faster (http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace-performance)

Comment: FYI - cellText.Replace(@"\u00A0", " ") did not work. Regex.Replace(cellText, @"\u00A0", " "); seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @DavidSchmitt this didn't work for me (vb.net) - but Regex.Replace did.

Comment: @gpmurthy Remember, strings are immutable, so the complete code line needs to be `cellText = cellText.Replace('\u00A0', ' ');`

Comment: The @ does stop escaping from working, but String.Regex will handle the escaping at runtime, while String.Replace will not.  3 things that work: (1) Regex.Replace(cellText, @"\u00A0", " ") (2) Regex.Replace(cellText, "\u00A0", " ") (3) cellText.Replace('\u00A0', ' ') Does NOT work: cellText.Replace(@"\u00A0", " ");

Answer (score 14):

It needs to be

```
text.Replace('\u00A0',' ')
```

where `\u00A0` is non breaking space

This will replace the non breaking space with normal space.

Comment: This works, saving the usage of Regex. Albeit the performance difference might be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest creating your own string comparer that extends one of the original ones -- do the "normalization" there (replace non-breaking space with regular space).  In addition to the instance `Equals` method, there's a static `String.Equals` that takes a comparer.

Answer (score -1):

The same without regex, mostly for myself when I need it later:

`text.Replace('\u00A0', ' ')`

Comment: You have given the expression in wrong order It should be text.Replace('\u00A0',' ')

Comment: @Gaurravs Indeed. I needed the other direction, hence the mistake.